# Is it possible a state that among two screen and able to setState from the two screens?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-state

I have occured this problem on my project.I really confused what I'm gonna do.

Comment: You can pass the setState as a prop to the screens. If this does not answer your question, please provide more details so the community can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A state can be passed to another screen with a parameter. See [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params) for further information.

Please beware that passing params [isn't meant to pass whole objects](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#what-should-be-in-params) but ids or queries of some kind.
In some cases you might want to think about state management with redux, mobx or zustand. However, this highly depends on the your problem.

Would be great to get some more details on your actual problem to be more helpful :-)

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params